# 'stoi' and 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have some code, it's quite large so I'll just create a snapshot of it here:

```
int l = 3;
vector<int> weights;   

void changeWeights(int out){
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++){
        int w = std::stoi(std::to_string(weights[i])) -
        out*std::stoi(std::to_string(weights[i]));
        if (w < -l){
          w = -l;
        } else if(w > l){
            w = l;
        }
        weights.assign(i, w);
    }
}
```

I get errors on both the 'stoi' and 'to_string' function calls in the form of

```
Main.cpp:35:21: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’
         int w = std::stoi(std::to_string(weights[i])) -
                 ^
Main.cpp:35:31: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
         int w = std::stoi(std::to_string(weights[i])) -
                           ^
Main.cpp:36:17: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’
         out*std::stoi(std::to_string(weights[i]));
             ^
Main.cpp:36:27: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’
         out*std::stoi(std::to_string(weights[i]));
```

I have read some similar queries whereby the answer was to add in -std=c++11 or -std=c++0x when compiling - both these solutions did not work. Another solution suggested a bug in the compiler version but it's not the compiler I am using I do not think. I am using g++ (GCC) 5.0.0 20141005 (experimental) version on a 64x Apple Macbook Pro.

Comment: Did you include `<string>`?

Comment: The prototype of stdio is: int       stoi( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = 0, int base = 10 );

Comment: Yes, I've changed to a compiler on a Linux virtual machine which is a temporary solution and don't really have the time to fix this issue but will come back to it later.

Comment: @LPs Nothing wrong in the OP's code regarding this.

Answer (score 4):

Usage of `stoi()` and `to_string()` in this part of code is pretty weird, and completely unnecessary. You can simply write

```
int w = weights[i] - out * weights[i];
```

---

To use [**`std::stoi()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and [**`std::to_string()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) you need to have a proper

```
#include <string>
```

statement, and the c++11 language options set (see the links to the documentation reference above).