# Error with stoi and debugged with gdb

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, coredump

My OS is ubuntu 14.04, laptop, i7.

The g++ version is `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`.

I tried to run a simple code to test `stoi`:

```
#include <string>
int main() 
{
   std::string s = "123";
   int i = std::stoi(s);
}
```

When I compile it with: `g++ -g prueba2.cpp`, I get:

```
prueba2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prueba2.cpp:6:12: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’
    int i = std::stoi(s);
            ^
```

When I debug it twice first with `g++ -std=c++0x -g prueba2.cpp` (I also tried with -std=c++11) and then with `dbg`, I got:

[image]

Then, I also did a simple search and followed the suggestions made in [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555504/stoi-and-to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std), [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145488/cygwin-g-stdstoi-error-stoi-is-not-a-member-of-std) and [here3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743904/stdstoi-missing-in-g-4-7-2), and none worked.

Am I doing something silly?

Comment: If the compiler gave you a fatal error, what makes you think it output runnable code?

Comment: So, what is the problem? Does it compile or not?

Comment: How can I solve it? I need more clues

Comment: Did it compile if you used `g++ -std=c++11 -g prueba2.cpp`?  If not what was the error?

Comment: Your code compiles fine and you got `exited normally` message. So, what is the problem?

Comment: How can you solve *what*?

Comment: When I add `std::cout << i << "\n";`, it prints nothing.

Comment: It [does for me](http://goo.gl/J8rGPt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think you're doing something pretty silly. You probably compiled the first code, which doesn't have the `std::cout` statement, and you probably executed the compilation steps without `-std=c++11` which would result in `std::stoi` not being included beecause `std::stoi` is from C++11 and onward. The result is still the old executable which prints out nothing.

Recompile using `-std=c++11` and make sure that you saved your file correctly. [Your code clearly works.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cb443dfded7d065)

Note: the vanilla port of GCC of MinGW on Windows is flawed and has a few bugs related to C++11 and onwards; using MinGW-w64, if you ever decide to compile on Windows, can help the problem.

Comment: yeap, it works properly like you say

Comment: It's always nice to help.

Answer (score 0):

`std::stoi` is a C++11 feature. Therefore your code only compiles, if you use the `-std=c++11` flags (or the equivalent `-std=c++0x` flag that you mentioned, which has *nothing* to do with debugging).

The terminal session you provided also shows that compilation works with those flags and your program runs fine without any problem. If you want to print the parsed result, you can do it like that: `std::cout << i << std::endl`

If you don't want to use C++11 features, you can use the `>>` stream operator to parse your string to an `int`:

```
stringstream ss(s);
int i;
ss >> n;
```

But beware: Other than with `stoi`, you won't get an exception, if your input doesn't contain a valid number. You will have to check the stream's status yourself.

Comment: ok, understood, it generates the file to gdb. Still, your answer is not a solution. how can I solve the general issue of `stoi`?

Comment: What is the "general issue"? It works fine. Just use it. And if you don't want to compile with C++11, you can use the stream operators to parse your input.

Comment: @beginner What is "general issue of `stoi`", There is no issue in your code.

Comment: When I add `std::cout << i << "\n";`, it prints nothing.

Comment: @beginner: Yes, it does: http://cpp.sh/3mfsf